# Get all records based on Model type in Polymorphic Relations

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphic-relationship

I have 3 Models and the related tables: Firm, SaleFirm, PartnerFirm.

In the Firms Table i want to store general informations about firms like name, bank account, ID and stuffs like this. In the other two tables i will store different informations based on the firm's type ( sale firm or partner firm ).

Beacuse of this logic, i need a polymorphic one-to-one relationship between this tables.

In my Firms Table i have this 2 columns: `firmable_id` and `firmable_type`.

The relationship between Firm Model and SaleFirm/PartnerFirm Model is this:

```
class Firm extends Model {
        public function firmable()
        {
                return $this->morphTo();
        }
}
```

```
class PartnerFirm extends Model {
        public function firm()
        {
                return $this->morphOne(Firm::class, 'firmable');
        }
}
```

My questions is this: How can i get all records based on `firmable_type`, so based on the Model name? Can i do this using the relationship or do i need to do something like this: `Firm::where('firmable_type','path\to\PartnerFirm')->get()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$firms = Firm::whereHasMorph('firmable', [PartnerFirm::class])->get();
```

This should output a query like this:

> => "select * from `firms` where ((`firmable_type` = ? and exists (select * from `partner_firms` where `firms`.`firmable_id` = `partner_firms`.`id`)))
>   and `firms`.`deleted_at` is null"

The way [Md. Miraj Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58998888/7117697) did it should also work:

```
$firms = Firm::whereHasMorph('firmable','App\PartnerFirm')->get();
```

It'll execute the same query:

> => "select * from `firms` where ((`firmable_type` = ? and exists (select * from `partner_firms` where `firms`.`firmable_id` = `partner_firms`.`id`)))
>   and `firms`.`deleted_at` is null"

In your reported error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has_morph' in 'where clause

It seems that is treating the method `whereHasMorph()` as a sugared version of the `where()` one (`where('has_morph', '...')`)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this to retrive your all Morph models like below. [Querying Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-polymorphic-relationships)

```
$PartnerFirm = Firm::whereHasMorph('firmable','App\PartnerFirm')->get();
```

Comment: This will throw me this error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has_morph' in 'where clause'"